# All divisions are integer results

Tags: objective-c

I'm dividing two numbers but the result is always a integer when it shouldn't. Here is my code:

```
NSUInteger photos = 57;
float result  = photos /2;

if((photos / 2) % 1 > 0)
{

    NSLog(@" result  %f", result);


}
```

The result should be 28.5 but for the print in console:

```
 p result
(float) $0 = 28
```

Any idea of what is going on or what I'm doing wrong?. I need to check if the division has a fraction to do something but is always false. I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: BTW - `x % 1` will always be `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you divide two integers, the resulting number will always be an integer.

Try dividing by `2.0` instead, as in `photos / 2.0`

Also, if all you want to know is whether there is a remainder to the integer division, you can use the `%` operator directly.

```
if(photos % 2 > 0) {
    //Do your stuff
}
```