# error: invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'float')

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to validate the division residue. Here is my code:

```
NSUInteger myNumber = 2;
//  list is a NSArray

if ((arrayImg.count / ((float) imgPerPage)) % 1 >0)
{
 // do something
}
```

but I get this error:

> error: invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'float')

if I do this:

```
float result = (arrayImg.count / ((float) imgPerPage));
```

works just fine but I don't understand why I use the %1 I get the error.

Any of you knows what is wrong with my code?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compute?

Comment: possible duplicate of [All divisions are integer results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567450/all-divisions-are-integer-results)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only use the modulo operator (`%`) with integer operands, so convert your floating point expression back to an integer first. Also it looks like you're trying to test for odd/even, so you need `% 2`, not `% 1`. So change:

```
if ((arrayImg.count / ((float) imgPerPage)) % 1 >0)
```

to:

```
if (((int)(arrayImg.count / (float) imgPerPage)) % 2 > 0)
```

Comment: Any (positive) integer `% 1` will always give *zero*, so that satisfies the compiler but might not solve the problem.

Comment: True - it's probably meant to be % 2 - it looks like the OP is trying to test for odd/even - answer updated.

Comment: You are probably right. Perhaps a confusion between `... & 1` and `... % 2`, already happened to me!